# How to keep one row for each unique column value after groupby in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a column of ids and a column of emails. I would like to group by id and only keep rows with distinct emails (it can be any row). For example:

```
+-------------------------------+
|    Id          Email          |
+-------------------------------+
|    1         email1           |
|    1         email2           |
|    1         email1           |
|    2         email3           |
|    2         email3           |
|    3         email4           |
|    3         email4           |
+-------------------------------+
```

The final output would be:

```
+---------------------------+
| Id            Email       |
+---------------------------+
| 1        email1           |
| 1        email2           |
| 2        email3           |
| 3        email4           |
+---------------------------+
```

The idea is something like

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY Id
HAVING DISTINCT(email)
```

but the syntax is not correct.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For this dataset, a simple `select distinct` should do:

```
select distinct id, email from mytable
```

This simply removes duplicate rows from the resultset, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: This would normally work, but I have other columns following ID and email that make the rows unique. The first table is the first two columns of the result of my query into another table. How can I modify the resulting query to get rows with unique (ID, email) pairings? In pandas it's a simple groupby ID followed by drop_duplicates("email"), but I'm unsure of how to translate this into mySQL.

Comment: Resolved! I grouped by concat(id, email) to get unique pairs of id, email